# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception:

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jpa, soap

I am working on a soap web service. I use JPA with namedquery annotation for data query. however using aggregated function like *sum* in combination with group by in my query resulted in some exceptions. my code is shown below.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name = "criteriatable")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries(
{
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Criteriatable c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.id =    :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findByCriteriaid", query = "SELECT c FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.criteriaid = :criteriaid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findBySubcriteriaid", query = "SELECT c FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.subcriteriaid = :subcriteriaid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findByProjectid", query = "SELECT c FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.findAllCriteriatableGroup", query = "SELECT c.criteriagroupname AS groupname, SUM(c.weight) AS groupweight  FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid GROUP BY c.criteriagroupname"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Criteriatable.SumAllWeightByProjectid", query = "SELECT SUM(c.weight) AS TotalProjectWeight FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid")    
})
  public class Criteriatable implements Serializable
{
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "weight")
private double weight;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "status")
private int status;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
@Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
@Column(name = "criteriagroupname")
```

WS Method

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getAllCriteriaGroupByProjectid")
public List<Criteriatable> getAllCriteriaGroupByProjectid(@WebParam(name = "projectid") int projectid)
{
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    String find = "Criteriatable.findAllCriteriatableGroup";
    TypedQuery<Criteriatable> query = em.createNamedQuery(find, Criteriatable.class);
    query.setParameter("projectid", projectid);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

and the error i receive is:

```
SEVERE:   Error occured
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: class [Ljava.lang.Object; nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

Please i need help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query `Criteriatable.findAllCriteriatableGroup` is not returning `Criteriatable` objects.

It is returning a list of [groupName, groupweight] tuples.

Remember that generic type information is not available at runtime, so your `List<Criteriatable>` collection at runtime will be a `List<Object[]>` (actually `List<Object[2]>`, but you can't write it that way).

This subsequently fails the JAXB mapping.

You need to define a POJO for your result:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GroupTotal {

    private String groupName;

    private double groupTotal;

    public GroupTotal(String groupName, double groupTotal) {
         this.groupName = groupName;
         this.groupTotal = groupTotal;
    }

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

amend your query:

```
SELECT NEW your.package.GroupTotal (c.criteriagroupname, SUM(c.weight))
  FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid GROUP BY c.criteriagroupname
```

and finally execute:

```
TypedQuery<GroupTotal> query = em.createNamedQuery(find, GroupTotal.class);
```

I haven't tried this but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @Steve_C can you help me still,  i still get error like:

Exception Description: Internal problem encountered while compiling [SELECT NEW GroupTotal (c.criteriagroupname, SUM(c.weight))FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid GROUP BY c.criteriagroupname].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE:   Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MamcaPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.

Comment: Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Internal problem encountered while compiling [SELECT NEW GroupTotal (c.criteriagroupname, SUM(c.weight))FROM Criteriatable c WHERE c.projectid = :projectid GROUP BY c.criteriagroupname].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i found the solution, i had to make a fully qualified classname for GroupTotal. thanks @Steve_c

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you return `List` from your web method. Try to return your own wrapper class which will have the list inside it as a field. Something like this

```
public class CriteriatablesWrapper {
    private List<Criteriatable> criteriatableList;
    // getter and setter
}
```

And change your service method signature to

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getAllCriteriaGroupByProjectid")
public CriteriatablesWrapper getAllCriteriaGroupByProjectid(@WebParam(name = "projectid") int projectid) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: to be honest what you have just done have confused me more. normally when i dont use the group by with teh sum function, i get my result. however my question is that is there a way to do this without any complications. i have an alternate method to do this but it not a good coding practice. i can join columns where i need the sum aggregate. if you can explain how i can do this wrapper class you wrote here i will be greatful

Comment: Oh, if it works without the group by then I didn't understand what your problem was. You need to compare the results with and without group by, and see exactly what object fails to marshal. Probably some of `Criteriatable`'s fields are empty without group by, and not empty with it, and that causes the problem.